# Making Balls Appear Constantly at Different Locations

Tags: java

I am a Java beginner, and I am trying to make a program in which white balls appear on the screen constantly. There should be a few seconds pause between one ball appearing before the next, and the balls need to appear at different places on the screen. I need help using the RandomGenerator to make the balls appear at different places. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

private RandomGenerator rgen = new RandomGenerator();

```
//~ Constructor ...........................................................

// ----------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Creates a new BubbleGame object.
 */
public void init()
{
    //call method to create regions
    CreateRegions();

    //add mouse listeners
    addMouseListeners();

    //loop to add bubbles
    while (true)
    {
        //create a filled bubble
        GOval bubble = new GOval (100, 100, 50, 50);
        bubble.setFilled(true);
        bubble.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        //randomly generate coordinates within the field
        int rgen = 

        //add the bubble and pause 
        add(bubble);
        Thread.sleep(3000);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Random.nextInt(maxInt)` to generate a number between 0 and maxInt-1.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
rnd.nextInt(10); // 0-9
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you're using Swing(or a similar technology). It is always a bad idea to use while(true) in the Event Dispatch Thread. Use a Swing Worker instead.

Random is quite easy to use. `Random.nextInt(n)` will give you an integer number between 0 and n-1.

You can also randomize the bubble color, its position and its size. It's your choice. You can make them disappear with mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

This function will fill an array with as menny random numbers as u pass _size, as the values and between _minVal & _maxVal. 
So if u need 4 cordinates pass 4 as size etc.

```
public int[] makeRanArray(int _Size, int _minVal, int _maxVal)
{
    int[] arr = new int[_Size];

    for (int i = 0; i < _Size; i++){ 
        arr[i] = _minVal + (int)(Math.random() * _maxVal);
    }
    return arr;
}
```